# What is the attribute AlwaysEnableSilent used for?

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I was looking at the raw HTML rendered by a SharePoint (2010) list item edit page, and I noticed that an input field (rich text field) made use of an AlwaysEnableSilent attribute.  i have checked online for an explanation of what the attribute does, but have not been able to get a answer.  Does anyone know what this attribute does?

Thanks, MagicAndi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.Net validators allow you to turn them on/off using client side scripting using ValidatorEnable, but whenever you turn the validator on that way the validation fires immediately. Sometimes you (SharePoint) may want to be able to control which validators are active using client side scripting, but without the validation firing when you turn it on (during load, before the users have had the possiblity to fill out the fields).

In order to handle this SharePoint has defined its own function STSValidatorEnable with an extra parameter bSilent, so it can turn on validators without them firing.

They then found out that for some validators they always want them not to fire when STSValidatorEnable is called, even though the caller uses bSilent==false. So they introduced an attribute AlwaysEnableSilent which tells the validator never to fire when turned on using STSValidatorEnable, but only during postback.

Comment: Per, thank you for your detailed answer. +1 and accepted as the answer.